# How to select ActiveRecord objects which have associated objects?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

E.g., if a Business has many Clients, how would I find the businesses which have at least one related client?

I've only figured out how to do it very inefficiently, e.g.:

```
Business.select { |b| !b.clients.empty? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joins

```
Business.joins(:clients)
```

This will create an inner join between Business and Client tables. It will return all Business which have atleast one Client.

Refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html